# Vertical Alignment with position: absolute

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center-align text (that may or may not span several lines) within a `<div>` that has `position: absolute` applied to it.

Please consider the following markup:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="test.jpg" />
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="#">Some long content</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS applied is as follows (please note that this is the LESS version):

```
.item {
    position: relative;

    img {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        text-align: center;

        a {
            color: #fff;
        }
    }
}
```

As well as being center-aligned horizontally, I'd like for the text within `.overlay` to be vertically aligned to the middle. I've tried adding the following:

```
.item {
    display: table;

    .overlay {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

I've also tried `inline-block` but nothing helps, since the element is absolutely positioned. I cannot use the usual `line-height` trick here, since the text may span several lines, and specifying a large line height will break the layout.

Does anyone know of a (relatively) cross-browser method to solve this issue? It needs to work in IE9+, FF and Chrome. If possible, I'd like to avoid adding any additional markup or 'divitis'.

I've put together a jsFiddle to demonstrate my issue (you'll also see the usual tricks work fine when the `position` != `absolute`):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element like `:before` and `inline-block` this way:

```
.item .overlay:before {
  content:" ";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
}
.item .overlay a {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/2/)**

<sub>You may need to handle the space between those inline-block items **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/3/)** I use margin-right</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your time. When I try to implement this, the `<h4>` element is pushed down > http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/5/

Comment: @BenM h4 are block elements for default as my example change the display the a tag in this case the h4 tag too http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/6/ ...

Comment: Np @BenM glad to help you

Comment: This does not render correctly in Firefox for me - http://screencast.com/t/PkxVGO9e2EN

Comment: See Danko's version in Mac Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/9/ vs. mine - http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/8/

Comment: @streetlogics please read the tiny letter under the demo fiddle .....  check this http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/10/ . Your solution implies more code lines

Comment: @streetlogics As I said again is the trick with inline-block ... http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/11/ ... and is crossbrowser. Just stop spam this answer

Answer (score 0):

Just make the absolute positioned element a "positioning" container, and put the actual element containers inside, like so - http://jsfiddle.net/Ggbtt/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150.jpg" />
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="inner-cell">
                <a href="#">Some long content</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    display: table;
}
    .item .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
        .inner-container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display:table;
        }
        .inner-cell {
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }
            .item .overlay a {
                color: #fff;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

If using absolute position, I find this solution to work every time

```
.item .overlay{
   top:50%;
   -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Well, it does align your overlay in the middle. Why the negative vote then ? You can apply the same method to your text also and it will work. Don't just copy but use your own code also.